# Can’t see files on an USB stick attached to a Raspberry PI 2

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have formated an USB stick from my Raspberry in `VFAT` and use it with Syncthing which works fine (dropping files from Windows 10, store them on the stick and access them on an Android Tablet).

But when on my RPI and trying to store files from it to the USB stick, I don’t see any file or directory.
Just prints `System Volume Information`.
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure but it may be that the pi is automounting the incorrect partition of your usb stick. Try this:

- Remove the USB stick from your Pi
- Open up a terminal
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/usb`
- Insert USB stick
- `sudo dmesg`
- Look at the last few lines, You should see something like `sdx: sdx1 sdx2`
- `sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/usb` Replace the sdx with the actual output on screen like `sdb1` for example
- `cd /mnt/usb` and see if your files are present.

If not, then try the below

- `cd /`
- `sudo mount -o remount /dev/sdx2 /mnt/usb`
- `cd /mnt/usb` Then check if your files are present.

This is purely based on some experiences I've had with USB drives and Linux, if you do not have multiple partitions on the USB then this will not be applicable.

Comment: Thanks. But I had to reformat the stick.